# Proxy setting in package.json not working

Tags: reactjs, express

I'm trying to successfully connect my backend Express app to my frontend React app but I'm having difficulty with the actual connection process and I think it's to do with the "proxy" pathway I'm using in my package.json file in my react app.

Express

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

let name = "Justin"

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(name)
})

app.listen(40000, () => {
  console.log("Im Listening on port 40000")
})
```

React

```
import './App.css';

function GetData() {
  fetch('/')
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then(function (data) {
    console.log(data)
  }
  )};
  
  
  


function App() {
  return (
    
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={GetData}>Get Data</button>
    </div>
  );
}


export default App;
```

I've made sure to add the proxy route to the express server within my package.json file

```
 "proxy": "http://localhost:40000",
```

The only thing that happens when I click the button is a text representation of the react app html page source.

What I want to see is the name "justin" displayed in the console when I click the button.

Would love a quick solve

Comment: Your express server can currently only do one thing: serve the word "Justin" when something accesses `/`. You haven't written anything that lets it actually service any other route yet, so it can't serve up html/css/js files yet. At the very least I assume you want an [express.static](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) binding so you can load static assets (including static html, css, and js files) from a public dir or something. That package.json doesn't need a proxy field, your server just needs more code to do the job you want it to do =)

Comment: How do I do that?  I feel like I'm close

Comment: By clicking on the link and reading how to do that =)

Comment: Oh I think you read my question wrong.  I don't want it to serve up any static files.  I was to pass a string, in this case my name to my frontend.  And in the future an arrayBuffer.  Do you have any suggestions about that?

Comment: If you're writing an API server: make your client-side code actually use the correct URL (because if your client's not served _by_ this server, you can't use relative links. Properly fetch `http://localhost:40000/`) and make the server reply with the correct content type header, as well as correct CORS headers (even if it's just `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`)